# What's the difference between Inactive and HoldForm?

Tags: core-language, hold, version-10, function-comparison

In version 10, Mathematica not only added `Inactive` / `Activate` but also highlighted this change in the ["New in 10"](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/) page (in Core Language Enhancements). Thus, I suppose it should be something useful. However, I didn't understand in which sense it is better than the good old `Hold` (`HoldForm`) / `ReleaseHold` mechanism. I noticed a few differences, but all of those are minor:

(1) `Inactive` objects are printed in a lighter color. `HoldForm` objects are printed in normal color.

(2) There is an `IgnoringInactive` function to include inactive objects into pattern matching.

It would be nice to hear if there are more important differences.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*Updated*

Both `Hold` and `Inactive` block evaluation; the key difference is that `Inactive` is meant to be wrapped around heads rather than a whole expression. `Inactivate` does this.

```
Inactivate[1 + 2 + 3 * 4 ^ 5 ] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Inactive[Plus][1, 2, Inactive[Times][3, Inactive[Power][4, 5]]]
> ```

It is of course possible to use `Inactive` directly, and it will behave like any symbol with holding attributes.

```
Inactive[1 + 2 + 3 * 4 ^ 5] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Inactive[Plus[1, 2, Times[3, Power[4, 5]]]]
> ```

But in general there is no reason to use it this way. Note that while `Activate` and `ReleaseHold` are comparable, there is no analog to `Inactivate`. The point is to use these auxiliary functions.

Because `Inactivate` wraps heads, it can accept an optional second argument constraining which heads to inactivate.

```
Inactivate[1 + 2 + 3 * 4 ^ 5, Plus] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Inactive[Plus][1, 2, 3072]
> ```

`Activate` can similarly accept an optional second argument.

```
Inactivate[1 + 2 + 3 * 4 ^ 5];
Activate[%, Power] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Inactive[Plus][1, 2, Inactive[Times][3, 1024]]
> ```

Another interesting consequence of using `Inactivate` is that atomic symbols will get evaluated.

```
Hold @ {$WolframUUID}
```

> ```
> Hold[{$WolframUUID}]
> ```

```
Inactivate @ {$WolframUUID}
```

> ```
> {"0e2497dc-9281-48f3-8e84-14b5e2587446"}
> ```

Comment: Thanks! But why don't they just add pattern matching or tags to `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`, but instead do something new and parallel?

Comment: I think it is just a design decision. In my opinion, the functionality is sufficiently different that it makes sense to use a different set of symbols. (Recall that `Unevaluated` also exists.)

Comment: @YiWang `Hold[A,B]` Already has a working definition (it will hold the sequence of elements), so if you add some sort of tags functionality to `Hold` you need to either get really creative or break backwards compatibility. But really, I don't think that there is any reason why Inactivate couldn't just wrap holds around heads and activate remove these holds. But personally I prefer the distinction.

Comment: But couldn't the effect of Inactivate also be achieved using `Hold` with `SetAttributes[MakeHeld, HoldAll]; MakeHeld[a_[b___]] := MakeHeld[a][b]; MakeHeld[a_] := Hold[a]`?

Comment: @celtschk Certainly; with that I only meant to highlight that they are *intended* to be used differently, but how you use them is of course flexible. The more subtle advantages of a different head are nicely pointed out in the other answers, and of course by the OP (`IgnoringInactive`).

Answer (score 19):

One difference is that `NDSolve` directly supports `Inactive`.  It can be used to specify operators such as divergence ($\nabla\cdot$) without automatically evaluating them to components.  This is described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1193699783).

Answer (score 12):

Although mfvonh's answer is a nice summary of `Inactive` formal properties, I think it misses several important points, which are both shown in the "Scope" and "Applications" section of the documentation. For me the main point seems to be (2), as I don't know how this could be achieved using `Hold`.

1) `Inactive` can be used to illustrate formal mathematical identities, e.g.,

```
Table[Block[{e = Inactivate[n + m]}, e == Activate[e]], {n, 0, 3}, {m,
 0, 3}] // Grid // TraditionalForm
```

2) It can be used in formal mathematical manipulations (as hinted at by Szabolcs' answer), e.g.,

```
D[Inactive[Integrate][f[x], {x, a[x], b[x]}],x]
(*-f[a[x]] Derivative[1][a][x] + f[b[x]] Derivative[1][b][x]*)
```

3) It can be used for easy programmatic code transformation, as `Inactivate` automatically wraps around all heads:

```
 def = Inactivate[for[f_, max_] := For[x = 1, x < max, x++, Print@x]];
 def/.Inactivate[For[i_ = init_, i_ < max_, i_++, body_] :> Do[body, {i, init, max}]]
 (*forSquares[f_,max_]:=Do[Print[f[x^2]],{x,1,max}]*)
```

So the use cases are quite different from the ones of `Hold`/`ReleaseHold`. I don't think (2) could be easily achieved with `Hold`, and (3) is definitely more elegantly solved by using `Inactivate`.

Comment: (2) is very interesting. But I didn't get the point of (1). When I run `Block[{e = HoldForm[23 + 11]}, e == ReleaseHold[e]]`, I get the same displayed result (though different `InputForm`).

Comment: @YiWang Oops, good point :) I didn't think of `HoldForm` because I never use it. The real point is probably in a more elaborate example (see edit). Now I'm crossing my fingers that I didn't overlook something else...

Answer (score 9):

I think the basic answer to your question is:

1) If you want absolute control over revaluation, nothing beats good old HoldComplete. It will be there to the end of time.

2) Inactive meant for much more targeted/slippy applications.  As such, it only wraps heads, not all arguments (as already noted by mfvonh).  You can control which heads get inactived.  And math is allowed to occur when there is an unambigous answer to an operation, which absolutely cannot happen with Hold. My personal favourite:

```
In[2]:= Curl[Inactive[Grad][f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
Out[2]= 0
```

In keeping with these applications, Inactivate ignores certains heads but default, most notably List.  This way, the strucutre of your data is unchanged and tensorial operations can be performed--very important in NDSolve.  The basic idea is Inactive[f] represents an inactive form of a desired operation, not some held expression which will be modified on manually.