# Elegant Replace Hold combination?

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style

I would like to define an distributive function like this:

```
com[x__Plus, y_] := c @@@ Distribute[c[x, y]];
```

which is Ok. I know that it's possible to define it simply exploiting the fact that `Plus` is `Flat`, but consider what I wrote just as a toy model of a more refined example.

Here the point is that I cannot write

```
com[x__Plus, y_] :=  Distribute[com[x, y]];
```

since I would have an infinite recursion. But is there a way to obtain the result I got in the first example without using that trick, just with `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
com[x__Plus, y_] := Distribute[Inactive[com][x, y]] // Activate
```

you get, for example,

```
com[Plus[a, b], c]
```

> `com[a, c] + com[b, c]`

Comment: I noticed that another solution can be `com[x__Plus, y_] := Distribute[HoldForm[com][x, y]] '. Do you have any suggestion when one has to choose between these two ways?

Comment: @MaPo When using `com[x__Plus, y_] := Distribute[HoldForm[com][x, y]]` the output is displayed as `com[a, c] + com[b, c]`, but its `FullForm` is `Plus[HoldForm[com][a,c],HoldForm[com][b,c]]`. One can get rid of these `HoldForm`s (assuming that's wanted) using `ReleaseHold`. I think you should add the `HoldForm` version as a self-answer.

Comment: @MaPo [What's the difference between Inactive and HoldForm?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54556/18476). For your case I don't see a practical difference between them.

Answer (score 6):

```
com[x__Plus, y_] := Block[{com}, Distribute[com[x, y]]]
```

This `Block`s the evaluation of `com` until after `Distribute` has done its work by momentarily treating `com` as a variable local to the `Block` scoping construct and hence momentarily losing all of its definitions and `Attribute`s.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated) here:

```
com[x__Plus, y_] := Distribute[Unevaluated @ com[x, y]]
```

Examples:

```
com[a+b, c]
com[a+b, c+d+e, f]
```

> com[a, c] + com[b, c]
>
> com[a, c, f] + com[a, d, f] + com[a, e, f] + com[b, c, f] + com[b, d, f] + 
>    com[b, e, f]

Answer (score 3):

> ***... just with `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` commands***

```
ClearAll[com]
com[x__Plus, y_] := ReleaseHold @ Distribute[Hold[com][x, y]]

com[a + b, c]
```

> com[a, c] + com[b, c]

```
com[a + b + c, d + e, f]
```

> com[a, d, f] + com[a, e, f] + com[b, d, f] + com[b, e, f] + 
>        com[c, d, f] + com[c, e, f]